# Each start-job fails

Tags: powershell, scripting

For example, if I enter `start-job -name newjob -scriptblock {get-process}` the job fails.

Subsequently entering `(get-job -name newjob).ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo`, I get something like

`System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: The background process reported an error with the following message: 2012-02-28 18:45:25 info    [native] No Registry-Settings exist for this process.`

What is the problem? (The WinRm service is running.)

Comment: Can we assume that running Get-Process normally works just fine?

Comment: No, each job that is started returns with state "failed"

Comment: No, without using jobs can you run Get-Process at a prompt without error? What OS are you running? The error seems to indicate something about a process called info. Can you tell us anything about it?

Comment: Yes, without using jobs everything works fine. I'm using Windows 7. The error message is independent of the command within the scriptblock. The "start-job" command has already worked on my machine, however something changed, I want to find out what :)

Comment: I see now. If you start a new PowerShell session do you still get the error? What about after a complete reboot?

Comment: Tried both options, using another computer I have no problem. However, I need to run these scripts on this machine :(

Comment: Did you try the tests with new-pssession and invoke-command? Perhaps re-running enable-psremoting?

Comment: No, I am not at work anymore...but I will try it first thing in the morning...thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the `PSRemotingTransportException` was a .NET profiling tool that changes the log output of the .NET processes. Apparently the background job process must return a certain log output. Disabling the initial logging of the profiling tool let the background jobs work again.

Answer (score 2):

I figured I might as well offer a more official answer. As you suggest, background jobs require PowerShell's remoting infrastructure, even to run local jobs. You've said the WinRM service is running, which is good. Can you create a "local" remote session by running New-PSSession?

PS C:> new-pssession

If remoting is working properly you should get a session object. If there is a problem then I would expect jobs to fail. You could try a new PowerShell session and/or rebooting. Or run Enable-PSRemoting again. I wonder if a GPO was pushed down that changed your remoting configuration.

You indicate that nothing runs with Start-Job. Try this command and see if it works:

invoke-command {get-process} -ComputerName $env:computername

It is similar in nature to Start-Job.

Comment: - Enable-PSRemoting --> done;
- new-pssession --> works;
- invoke-command {get-process} -ComputerName $env:computername --> works;
however, start-job still fails

Comment: So remoting works but anything you run with Start-Job fails. What happens if you try this:

get-wmiobject win32_service -asjob

I am going to assume it will fail but better to be thorough.

Comment: I decided to install Windows Management Framework 3.0 - Community Technology Preview (including PowerShell 3), now it works...Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suspect something was borked in the .NET Framework on that machine.  But now you also get the goodness of PowerShell 3.0.